# datahub s3 metadata ingestion needs Spark installed

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am trying to get the metadata from a bucket/prefix on S3 using datahub but i am getting error:
`{logger:26} - Please set env variable SPARK_VERSION.` 
The datahub s3 documentation mentions
`Profiles are computed with PyDeequ, which relies on PySpark. Therefore, for computing profiles, we currently require Spark 3.0.3 with Hadoop 3.2 to be installed and the SPARK_HOME and SPARK_VERSION environment variables to be set.`

Where should i install Spark and SPARK_VERSION? In the container? I have Spark locally installed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue, when ingesting s3 from datahub UI, it will throw exception about "SPARK_VERSION env is not set", but how to set this env using the ingestion UI? I can ingest successfully using datahub command where I can set the environment.
p.s. With my experience, you do not need to install spark, just install the plugin (pip install 'acryl-datahub[s3]') and set the SPARK_VERSION env is enough for command ingestion. (datahub v0.14)